# Android Studio: I simply cannot get my app to work - blank screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I just can't get my app to work. When I open it on my phone, the screen is white. I don't get any errors when cleaning or generating the signed apk.

I've gone back and reverted all my changes (I think, pretty sure) to the point where I had it working.

If someone could look through my code and tell me what's wrong that would be awesome:

Thanks for the help! :)

Here is the code I edited.

MainFragment.java

```
package com.thesgn.app.fragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.thesgn.app.R;
import com.thesgn.app.WebViewAppConfig;
import com.thesgn.app.utility.DownloadUtility;
import com.thesgn.app.utility.Logcat;
import com.thesgn.app.utility.MediaUtility;
import com.thesgn.app.utility.NetworkManager;
import com.thesgn.app.view.ViewState;

import java.io.File;


public class MainFragment extends TaskFragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener
{
    private static final String ARGUMENT_URL = "url";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_SHARE = "share";
    private static final int REQUEST_FILE_PICKER = 1;

private boolean mActionBarProgress = false;
private ViewState mViewState = null;
private View mRootView;
private String mUrl = "about:blank";
private String mShare;
private boolean mLocal = false;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mFilePathCallback4;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback5;


public static MainFragment newInstance(String url, String share)
{
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();

    // arguments
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_URL, url);
    arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_SHARE, share);
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);

    return fragment;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    // handle fragment arguments
    Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if(arguments != null)
    {
        handleArguments(arguments);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return mRootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // restore webview state
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    // setup webview
    renderView();

    // pull to refresh
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_swipe_refresh);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    // load and show data
    if(mViewState==null || mViewState==ViewState.OFFLINE)
    {
        loadData();
    }
    else if(mViewState==ViewState.CONTENT)
    {
        showContent();
    }
    else if(mViewState==ViewState.PROGRESS)
    {
        showProgress();
    }
    else if(mViewState==ViewState.EMPTY)
    {
        showEmpty();
    }

    // progress in action bar
    showActionBarProgress(mActionBarProgress);
}


@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
}


@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}


@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView()
{
    super.onDestroyView();
    mRootView = null;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_FILE_PICKER)
    {
        if(mFilePathCallback4!=null)
        {
            Uri result = intent==null || resultCode!=Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            if(result!=null)
            {
                String path = MediaUtility.getPath(getActivity(), result);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                mFilePathCallback4.onReceiveValue(uri);
            }
            else
            {
                mFilePathCallback4.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
        }

        if(mFilePathCallback5!=null)
        {
            Uri result = intent==null || resultCode!=Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            if(result!=null)
            {
                String path = MediaUtility.getPath(getActivity(), result);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
                mFilePathCallback5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{ uri });
            }
            else
            {
                mFilePathCallback5.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback4 = null;
        mFilePathCallback5 = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    // save current instance state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    setUserVisibleHint(true);

    // save webview state
    WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    webView.saveState(outState);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    // action bar menu
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // show or hide share button
    MenuItem share = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share);
    share.setVisible(mShare!=null && !mShare.trim().equals(""));
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
    // action bar menu behaviour
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.menu_share:
            startShareActivity(getString(R.string.app_name), mShare);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


@Override
public void onRefresh()
{
    runTaskCallback(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            refreshData();
        }
    });
}


private void handleArguments(Bundle arguments)
{
    if(arguments.containsKey(ARGUMENT_URL))
    {
        mUrl = arguments.getString(ARGUMENT_URL);
        mLocal = mUrl.contains("file://");
    }
    if(arguments.containsKey(ARGUMENT_SHARE))
    {
        mShare = arguments.getString(ARGUMENT_SHARE);
    }
}


private void loadData()
{
    if(NetworkManager.isOnline(getActivity()) || mLocal)
    {
        // show progress
        showProgress();

        // load web url
        WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
        webView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        showOffline();
    }
}


public void refreshData()
{
    if(NetworkManager.isOnline(getActivity()) || mLocal)
    {
        // show progress in action bar
        showActionBarProgress(true);

        // load web url
        WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
        webView.loadUrl(webView.getUrl());
    }
    else
    {
        showActionBarProgress(false);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.global_offline_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private void showActionBarProgress(boolean visible)
{
    // show pull to refresh progress bar
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_swipe_refresh);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(visible);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(!visible);

    mActionBarProgress = visible;
}


private void showContent()
{
    // show content container
    ViewGroup containerContent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_content);
    ViewGroup containerProgress = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_progress);
    ViewGroup containerOffline = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_offline);
    ViewGroup containerEmpty = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_empty);
    containerContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    containerProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerOffline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mViewState = ViewState.CONTENT;
}


private void showContent(final long delay)
{
    final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            runTaskCallback(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    if(getActivity()!=null && mRootView!=null)
                    {
                        Logcat.d("Fragment.timerRunnable()");
                        showContent();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, delay);
}


private void showProgress()
{
    // show progress container
    ViewGroup containerContent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_content);
    ViewGroup containerProgress = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_progress);
    ViewGroup containerOffline = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_offline);
    ViewGroup containerEmpty = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_empty);
    containerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    containerOffline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mViewState = ViewState.PROGRESS;
}


private void showOffline()
{
    // show offline container
    ViewGroup containerContent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_content);
    ViewGroup containerProgress = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_progress);
    ViewGroup containerOffline = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_offline);
    ViewGroup containerEmpty = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_empty);
    containerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerOffline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    containerEmpty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mViewState = ViewState.OFFLINE;
}


private void showEmpty()
{
    // show empty container
    ViewGroup containerContent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_content);
    ViewGroup containerProgress = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_progress);
    ViewGroup containerOffline = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_offline);
    ViewGroup containerEmpty = (ViewGroup) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.container_empty);
    containerContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerOffline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    containerEmpty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mViewState = ViewState.EMPTY;
}


private void renderView()
{
    // reference
    final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    final AdView adView = (AdView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_adview);

    // webview settings
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.global_bg_front));
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); // fixes scrollbar on Froyo
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback)
        {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }


        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback filePathCallback, String acceptType)
        {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }


        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback, String acceptType, String capture)
        {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
            mFilePathCallback5 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"), REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        private boolean mSuccess = true;


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url)
        {
            runTaskCallback(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    if(getActivity()!=null && mSuccess)
                    {
                        showContent(500); // hide progress bar with delay to show webview content smoothly
                        showActionBarProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(final WebView view, final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl)
        {
            runTaskCallback(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    if(getActivity()!=null)
                    {
                        mSuccess = false;
                        showEmpty();
                        showActionBarProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if(DownloadUtility.isDownloadableFile(url))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.fragment_main_downloading, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                DownloadUtility.downloadFile(getActivity(), url, DownloadUtility.getFileName(url));
                return true;
            }
            else if(url!=null && (url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")))
            {
                // determine for opening the link externally or internally
                boolean external = isLinkExternal(url);
                boolean internal = isLinkInternal(url);
                if(!external && !internal)
                {
                    external = WebViewAppConfig.OPEN_LINKS_IN_EXTERNAL_BROWSER;
                }

                // open the link
                if(external)
                {
                    startWebActivity(url);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    showActionBarProgress(true);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if(url!=null && url.startsWith("mailto:"))
            {
                MailTo mailTo = MailTo.parse(url);
                startEmailActivity(mailTo.getTo(), mailTo.getSubject(), mailTo.getBody());
                return true;
            }
            else if(url!=null && url.startsWith("tel:"))
            {
                startCallActivity(url);
                return true;
            }
            else if(url!=null && url.startsWith("sms:"))
            {
                startSmsActivity(url);
                return true;
            }
            else if(url!=null && url.startsWith("geo:"))
            {
                startMapSearchActivity(url);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if(webView.canGoBack())
                        {
                            webView.goBack();
                            return true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN); // http://android24hours.blogspot.cz/2011/12/android-soft-keyboard-not-showing-on.html
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(!v.hasFocus())
                    {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    // admob
    if(WebViewAppConfig.ADMOB && NetworkManager.isOnline(getActivity()))
    {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.admob_test_device_id))
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


private void controlBack()
{
    final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    if(webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();
}


private void controlForward()
{
    final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    if(webView.canGoForward()) webView.goForward();
}


private void controlStop()
{
    final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    webView.stopLoading();
}


private void controlReload()
{
    final WebView webView = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_webview);
    webView.reload();
}


private void startWebActivity(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private void startEmailActivity(String email, String subject, String text)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("mailto:");
        builder.append(email);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(builder.toString()));
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private void startCallActivity(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private void startSmsActivity(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private void startMapSearchActivity(String url)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private void startShareActivity(String subject, String text)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e)
    {
        // can't start activity
    }
}


private boolean isLinkExternal(String url)
{
    for(String rule : WebViewAppConfig.LINKS_OPENED_IN_EXTERNAL_BROWSER)
    {
        if(url.contains(rule)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}


private boolean isLinkInternal(String url)
{
    for(String rule : WebViewAppConfig.LINKS_OPENED_IN_INTERNAL_WEBVIEW)
    {
        if(url.contains(rule)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!--
This is a configuration file for navigation menu. You can add/remove/modify menu items as you need.
Important: each of these 4 arrays below must contain the same number of items.
-->

<!-- List of titles in navigation drawer menu -->
<string-array name="navigation_title_list">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Forums</item>
    <item>Events</item>
    <item>Streams</item>
    <item>Media</item>
    <item>Members</item>
    <item>Blogs</item>
    <item>SGN Code</item>
    <item>Help and FAQs</item>
    <item>Search</item>
</string-array>

<!--
List of webview URLs. You can specify URL link to a web page on the Internet or
URL link to a local page stored in assets directory. Local page does not require Internet connection.
URL to the local page must be in this format: file:///android_asset/example.html
-->
<string-array name="navigation_url_list">
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/forums</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/events</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/streams</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/media</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/members-list</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/blogs</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/coc</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/help</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/search</item>
</string-array>

<!-- List of icons in navigation drawer menu -->

<string-array name="navigation_icon_list">
    <item>@drawable/home</item>
    <item>@drawable/chat</item>
    <item>@drawable/calendar</item>
    <item>@drawable/streams</item>
    <item>@drawable/media</item>
    <item>@drawable/members</item>
    <item>@drawable/blog</item>
    <item>@drawable/cod</item>
    <item>@drawable/help</item>
    <item>@drawable/search</item>
</string-array>


<!--
List of share messages. Each webview page can be shared via e-mail, sms, social networks etc.
Share button is in the action bar. You can specify a message which gonna be posted.
If you don't want to share the page, keep the item empty.
-->
<string-array name="navigation_share_list">
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/forums</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/events</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/streams</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/media</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/members-list</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/blogs</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/coc</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/help</item>
    <item>http://thesgn.com/board/search</item>
</string-array>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<!-- LANGUAGE INDEPENDENT -->
<string name="app_name">TheSGN</string>

<!-- LANGUAGE DEPENDENT -->
<string name="global_offline_toast">No Internet connection available</string>

<string name="menu_share">Share</string>

<string name="drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
<string name="drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

<string name="placeholder_empty">Not found</string>
<string name="placeholder_offline">No Internet connection available</string>

<string name="fragment_main_downloading">Downloading…</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you post  fragment_main.xml? I think your app is running fine just that you are not seeing any data.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment you should use `onViewCreated` instead of `onActivityCreated`